# How can I filter questions that are answered/unanswered?

Tags: python, django

In attempting to replicate the unanswered QuerySet functionality of Stack Overflow, I'm left stuck how
this would be done at the table level? How would I go about implementing a QuerySet where it returns all unanswered questions when the Question model doesn't have any foreign key reference to Answer on the table itself? It's only when an individual question has been queried that reverse relationship of answers can be accessed.

```
class QuestionStatusQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def unanswered(self):
        pass

    def newest(self):
        pass


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    dated = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserAccount',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="questions"
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='questions')

    objects = models.Manager()
    dateranges = DateRangeQuerySet.as_manager()
    status = QuestionStatusQuerySet.as_manager()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dated']
        default_manager_name = "objects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="answers"
    )
    response = models.TextField()
    dated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserAccount',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="answers"
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-likes']
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try like this using [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull):

```
class QuestionStatusQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def unanswered(self):
        self.filter(answers__isnull=True)

    def newest(self):
        self.order_by('-dated')[0]
```